# Is there anyway i can get headers on a row while converting json to csv using papaparse

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, csv, papaparse

I want to convert json to csv
In papaparse it is working properly but i want to convert it in row wise
For example

```
 1. a            b         c         d
 -
 2. Heading 1 answer 1_0 answer 1_1 answer 1_2
 3. Heading 2 answer 2_0 answer 2_1 answer 2_2
```

And so on
So is there any feature for it , I can use it
code:

```
let csv = Papa.unparse(newArray,{
      quotes: false, //or array of booleans
      quoteChar: '"',
      escapeChar: '"',
      delimiter: ",",
      header: true,
      newline: "\r\n",
      skipEmptyLines: false, //other option is 'greedy', meaning skip delimiters, quotes, and whitespace.
      columns: indexes //or array of strings
    });
    console.log(csv);
```

output I receive:-
[output 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZXtX.png)

output I want :
[output 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGSqj.png)

Thanks

Comment: What did you try to do? Where's your code?

Comment: @Mohamed.Karkotly updated please give any solutions if you know

Comment: To optimize the solution, could you please confirm that you want to use the solution inside a `Node.js` project?

Comment: yes @Mohamed.Karkotly nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Considering your data, the output you are getting in Vanilla JS is something like this:

```
var csv = [
  ["task", "assignee", "date", "remarks"],
  ["1", "abc", "dd/mm/yyyy", "-"],
  ["2", "def", "dd/mm/yyyy", "-"],
];
```

Now what we need to do is actually inversing the columns to become rows and rows to become columns.

There's one function that can do this all in [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) which is a library I suggest. For installation use the command

```
npm install underscore
```

And then in your module

```
var _ = require('underscore');
```

Inverse code:

```
var inversedData = _.zip(...data);
console.log(inversedData);
```

### As per Vanilla JS solution

```
var data = [
  ["task", "assignee", "date", "remarks"],
  ["1", "abc", "dd/mm/yyyy", "-"],
  ["2", "def", "dd/mm/yyyy", "-"],
];
var inversedArray = data;
const zip = () => {
  inversedArray = data.map((value, idx) => [value, ...data.map((data) => data[idx])]);
  console.warn(inversedArray);
};
```